# Map-reduce framework in D lang

Tags: mapreduce, d

looking for any map-reduce framework (even the smallest one) written in D.

Is there anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

For basic map reduce funcionality you can use phobos library.

For non-parallel task use std.algorithm http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#map and
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#reduce

For parallel use std.parallelism: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.TaskPool.map and http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.TaskPool.reduce

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm still looking for something more than just the standard library. For example, Python has almost the same functions but for a real-world MR framework it's not enough - there should be sorting, at least. So that's why there are at least 3  Python MR frameworks - they just simplify things. So I was looking for something similar

Comment: @Spaceman no offense, but you asked for map-reduce, and the answer above is absolutely relevant. If you want more, then change your question.

Comment: @DejanLekic I didn't ask for map-reduce functionality. I asked for map-reduce framework. Probably you haven't worked with any of existing MR frameworks and with this technology in general. There is a lot more beyond just 'map' and 'reduce' functions: splitting the data between workers, sorting, combining - even in the simplest. Googling and reading sources of some - even simplest - MR frameworks, such as Mincemeat or Octopy, might help.

Answer (score 1):

There is [MapReduce-MPI](http://mapreduce.sandia.gov/doc/Manual.html). It is written in C++ but [callable from C](http://mapreduce.sandia.gov/doc/Interface_c.html), which means callable from D.

keep in mind though there is no fault tolerance because MPI doesn't have fault tolerance.